# Junit - testing call to obj.wait()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, wait, powermock

I'm trying to write a junit to test the use of java monitors in my code. Is there a way a assert that wait() has been called on a particular object. I tried different combinations of obj and mockito spy to partially stub it but it either throws IllegalMonitorStateException or just keeps waiting instead of catching the method call.

```
public void waitTest(){
   RWLock lock= new RWLock();
   RWLock lockSpy = spy(lock);

   lock.lockRead();
   synchronized (lockSpy) {
        verify(lockSpy).wait();
   }
}

class RWLock{
    public synchronized void lockRead(){
        wait();
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the mockito code.

Comment: I'm using mockito spy here:
RWLock lockSpy = spy(lock); //to create a spy
and
verify(lockSpy).wait(); //to check

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `wait()` is final.   Mockito can't verify final methods.

Comment: ok, I see. Is there any other way to do this? Say, using powermock?

Comment: @mind It's not a framework restriction. It's a proxying restriction. Because the method is final, it cannot (easily) be proxied.

Comment: I'm not a PowerMock expert, so I can't comment.  It's very possible that it will work.  You could try it.  But there's a bigger issue here.  I don't see why you want to test that `wait` gets called.  Your class must have some required behaviour, that doesn't necessarily depend on what methods get called internally.  Can't you just test the behaviour, rather than testing implementation details?